# Calendar - current week

Tags: views, 6, datetime

I am looking for a way to add a class to the  week row indicating whether the week is the current week.

The week is rendered by `calendar-month-row.tpl.php` and the arguments are passed within `calendar_build_month()`.

What is the "Drupal way" of intercepting this procedure?

I of course do not want to hack the module to generate the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Copy template file
`sites/all/modules/calendar/theme/calendar-month-row.tpl.php`
to
`sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME/templates` directory and edit it in this manner:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Template to display a row
 * 
 * - $inner: The rendered string of the row's contents.
 */
$attrs = ($week > 0) ? 'week="' . $week . '"' : '';
$attrs .= ($iehint > 0) ? ' iehint="' . $iehint . '"' : '';
if ($week == date('W')) $class .= ' calendar-current-week';
$attrs .= ($class) ? ' class="' . $class . '"': '';
?>
<?php if ($attrs != ''):?>
<tr <?php print $attrs?>>
<?php else:?>
<tr>
<?php endif;?>
  <?php print $inner ?>
</tr>
```

Don't forget to clear page cache after this.